# Make PROCEDURE for insertn new bill from table order . is this right in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my code about PROCEDURE  . is this right i just want to make a procedures to insert new bill 
and all the data is here and i need that from one table .
the columns in this data is in my query . but i still want to know if is this error .
thanks

```
USE [Northwind]
    GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Orders]
(
    @OrderID int , 
    @CustomerID nvarchar(5),
    @EmployeeID int ,
    @OrderDate datetime,
    @RequiredDate datetime,
    @ShippedDate datetime,
    @ShipVia int,
    @Freight money, 
    @ShipName nvarchar(40),
    @ShipAddress nvarchar(60),
    @ShipCity nvarchar(15),
    @ShipRegion nvarchar(15),
    @ShipPostalCode nvarchar(10),
    @ShipCountry nvarchar(15)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.Orders
    ( 
       OrderID,
           CustomerID,
           EmployeeID,
           OrderDate,
           RequiredDate,
           ShippedDate,
           ShipVia,
           Freight, 
           ShipName,
           ShipAddress,
           ShipCity,
           ShipRegion,
           ShipPostalCode,
           ShipCountry
    ) 
        VALUES 
    (
           @OrderID,
           @CustomerID,
           @EmployeeID,
           @OrderDate,
           @RequiredDate,
           @ShippedDate,
           @ShipVia,
           @Freight,
           @ShipName,
           @ShipAddress,
           @ShipCity,
           @ShipRegion,
           @ShipPostalCode,
           @ShipCountry                       
    )
END    
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[proc_Orders]
    @OrderID = N'My Order',
        @CustomerID = 0,
        @EmployeeID = 0,
        @OrderDate = N'2014-1-1',
        @RequiredDate = N'2014-1-1',
        @ShippedDate = N'2014-1-1',
        @ShipVia = 0,
        @Freight = 0,
        @ShipName = 0,
        @ShipAddress = 0, 
        @ShipCity = 0 , 
        @ShipRegion = 0 ,
        @ShipPostalCode = 0,
        @ShipCountry = 0 

Declare @RC int
Execute @RC = dbo.proc_Orders
         'My Order',0,0,N'2014-1-1',N'2014-1-1',N'2014-1-1',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
```

Comment: If you need some additional logic: Yes, otherwise too much overkill.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO dbo.orders
(
column list
)
SELECT
column list
FROM
dbo.Bill where orderid = @var

By doing this way , you need to pass only the OrderID alone as the parameter to the procedure.